# Derivative of quadratic form involving singularity

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, discrete-mathematics, quadratics

This might be a silly question, but i have been really curious about the following:

Consider the following function seen thru a single variable, say $\alpha$:

\begin{equation}
f(\alpha) = \mathbf{x}^{H}(\alpha) \mathbf{A}^{-1}(\alpha) \mathbf{x}(\alpha)
\end{equation} 
where $\mathbf{x}(\alpha) \in \mathbb{C}^{N \times 1}$ and $\mathbf{A}(\alpha) \in \mathbb{C}^{N \times N}$.

I am interested in the $1^{st}$ and $2^{nd}$ order derivatives of $f(\alpha)$ at $\alpha_0$. However, $\mathbf{A}(\alpha_0)$ is singular, and is rank $N-1$.

I just want to check, even though it might be clear, that the $1^{st}$ and $2^{nd}$ order derivatives of $f(\alpha)$ at $\alpha_0$ do not exist. I even tried regularising by substituing $\mathbf{A}(\alpha)$ by $\mathbf{A}(\alpha) + \gamma \mathbf{I}$, where $\gamma$ goes to zero, but the results i get are not satisfying, i.e. regularising does not help.

I am actually interested in the ratio $\frac{f'(\alpha_0)}{f''(\alpha_0)}$. It turns out that regularising does not help.

P.S: I know that i could have a pseudo-inverse instead of the inverse. But i am interested in $f(\alpha)$ peaking up at value $\alpha_0$. If i put a pseudo-inverse, then the latter would not occur.

Comment: Can we not just have $f(\alpha)=\frac{\mathbf x^{H+1}(\alpha)}{\mathbf A(\alpha)}$, and must we use the special letters?  I'd rather not to be honest.

Comment: Hi, I'm not familiar with your notation. Thanks anyways.

Comment: Consider the following:  to be differentiable, it must be a continuous function, so $x(\alpha)$ and $A(\alpha)$ to make up a continuous function.  Also, since you tagged this question with "discrete-mathematics", does that imply these are discrete functions?  Discrete functions aren't differentiable.